# merge or concat two rows in same Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7

I have one dataframe where there are 4 records, for 1 ConfigID(with B & G) we have two rows, Need to replicate the row with value into the row where there is no value. Is it possible in python? Please click "DF" below for the example

```
dataFrame_Original = pd.DataFrame(
   {
      "Region": ['1701656754', '', '1601656754', ''],
      "Directory": [153623, '', 153623, ''],
      "MigrDate": ['20221213', '', '20221214', ''],
      "MigrFrm": ['NBD Wty, Contract', '', 'Orlando, Contract', ''],
      "MigrTo": ['AMK1', '', 'AMK2', ''],
      "MemID": ['FI00', '', 'FI08', ''],
      "Ponts": ['854621544', '', '521354662', ''],
      "Eroom": ['FINNISH POST TIME DE', '', 'English Pre Dent', ''],
      "ConfigID": ['84460001B', '84460001G', '34460001B', '34460001G'],
      "Duration": ['AM02', 'AMK1', 'AUM02', 'AUMK1']
    }
)

print(dataFrame_Original)

dataFrame_Expected = pd.DataFrame(
   {
      "Region": ['1701656754', '1701656754', '1601656754', '1601656754'],
      "Directory": [153623, '153623', 153623, '153623'],
      "MigrDate": ['20221213', '20221213', '20221214', '20221214'],
      "MigrFrm": ['NBD Wty, Contract', 'NBD Wty, Contract', 'Orlando, Contract', 'Orlando, Contract'],
      "MigrTo": ['AMK1', 'AMK1', 'AMK2', 'AMK2'],
      "MemID": ['FI00', 'FI00', 'FI08', 'FI08'],
      "Ponts": ['854621544', '854621544', '521354662', '521354662'],
      "Eroom": ['FINNISH POST TIME DE', 'FINNISH POST TIME DE', 'English Pre Dent', 'English Pre Dent'],
      "ConfigID": ['84460001B', '84460001G', '34460001B', '34460001G'],
      "Duration": ['AM02', 'AMK1', 'AUM02', 'AUMK1']
   }
)
print(dataFrame_Expected)
```

[image]

Comment: instead of image, can you put the data in textual format, better in `pd.DataFrame(...)` format

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/6660638/epsi95
I have modified the comment with df

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first DF has 4 records out of which there are 4 configID where top 2 and bottom 2 are same with suffix G and B to it. all records for ConfigID ending B are populated whereas Most of the records for ConfigID G are blank. I want to copy the data from the populated value to blank for same configID(if we strip G and B).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for a simple [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```py
dataFrame_Original = dataFrame_Original.replace("", None).ffill()
```

First replace the cells which only contain a `''` with `None` and then forward fill.